# Background error on iphone/ipad via Tumblr custom theme

Tags: iphone, css, background-image, tumblr

I have reskinned http://peggywho.com with a fixed background in Tumblr. However, as I am adding posts to the website, the mobile view in ipad and iphone doesn't allow the background to stretch across the page. It has black space at the top and bottom (I'm unable to add an image as I am new here)

custom CSS for the background is as follows:

```
body {
margin-top:15px;
background-position:center center;
background-image:url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2633376/PS_web_BG_01.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

I am relatively new to coding so still learning my way around. Is there anything to add to the HTML or CSS that would allow mobile viewing to replicate the website, which looks the way I want it to look?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it kinda looks like your div id="content" is covering it I recommend setting img, a img, a:hover img {border: 0!important;max-width:100%;} instead of being 500px and also set your #content to 100% also. Let me know how it goes I can help

Comment: Thank you for replying! I'm afraid that didn't work. Setting #content to 100% made the posting container across the entire width of the page, which isn't what I want. I like the compact, central container for the posts. The site looks fine on mobile asides from the background issue.

Comment: ok try this `/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
#posts{rgba(187, 186, 186, 0.5);}
}`

Comment: and for ipads `/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
 #posts{rgba(187, 186, 186, 0.5);
}`

Comment: the a in rgba is a value that controls opacity so you can make it transparent and you'll see that the background does extend the full width